# Reserve cells if conditions are met

Tags: excel, vba

I have one problem that I need to solve and is as following. I would like to insert data into cells if conditions are met. Conditions are from cells M1 to M3 and this cells are in dropdown list.
Cell M1 is column B:B
Cell M2 is column C:C
Cell M3 is column D:D
Cell M4 is typed manualy
Cell M5 is a number and is also typed manualy(randoml)

Once I defined from dropdown cells M1 to M3 and type some text in cell M4 and type a number in cell M5, program should insert in column H cell M4, in column I program should automaticaly insert today date and in column J sould automaticaly insert actual time. In how many cells should be this inserted is defined in cell M5. If in some part of the table, row are reserved, macro should skip this already inserted data

If from the table there is no free/empty cells, then the program should inform a user with a notification[image]

Could you please help me to create a macro to automaticaly insert data into cells

Thank you

I try this in attached table, but unfirtunately, results are not this what I expected

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub code_res()

Dim lr As Long, r As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim iSheet As Worksheet
Dim ans As Integer

Set iSheet = Worksheets("List1")

lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

i = 0

Cells(4, 14) = 0

For r = 7 To lr

If Cells(r, 2) = Cells(1, 13) And Cells(r, 3) = Cells(2, 13) And Cells(r, 7) = "" Then
Cells(r, 7) = Cells(3, 13)
Cells(r, 9) = Date
With Cells(r, 10)
.Value = Time
.NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"
i = i + 1
If i = Cells(4, 13) Then
    Exit For
End If
End With
End If
Next r

iSheet.Range("M4") = 
iSheet.Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(iSheet.Range("H:H"), 
iSheet.Range("M3"))

'testing quantity and export
If Cells(4, 13) > Cells(4, 14) Then
ans = MsgBox("Quantity of reservation " & Cells(4, 14), vbQuestion + vbYesNo,"Do you want to do a export?")
    If ans = vbYes Then
        Call Izvoz1 'data export
    Else
        MsgBox "Data are not exported"
    End If
Else
Call Izvoz1 'data export
MsgBox "Succesesfully exported"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).